# Scan Disk then Defrag, or Defrag then Scan Disk (in Windows)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, defragment, scan-disk

Which one should I do first in Windows 7? Scan Disk or Defragmenter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan disk first, as defrag will fail if it hits a bad block.  Actually, I am pretty sure defrag does a scan disk first to make sure there are no issues before proceeding, but it is still the same sequence.

Comment: Yeah, I think the old defrag unnder Windows 95 would ask you to run scandisk first.

Comment: So if we scan disk then defrag we end up scanning twice since defrag rescans the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the defraggers will not defrag a "dirty" disk, as it would be incorrect to try and defrag a disk that is "dirty". Dirty means that it stopped (was stopped) without finishing something. You (or the program(s) should always check the disk first before defragging.

If you are having disk "problems" it might be very unwise to defrag it at all. if your having disk problems because of memory issues, it can be bad to checkdisk or defrag :-).   If the problems that the disk is having are not just a Crash, and a cleanup from the crash, you should address any disk or memory issues before doing either. If it is just a crash, then no problem.